# Erro ao incluir na base de dados: Duplicate entry '-1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, mysqli

Amigos tenho esta tabela, quando vou salvar um usuário o seguinte erro ocorre

> Erro ao incluir na base de dados: Duplicate entry 'nome.sobrenome -1'
> for key 'PRIMARY'

Esse é o código. detalhe em desenvolvimento funciona, em produção não.

```
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `login` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `passe` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `activation_code` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin_pv` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `foto` longblob,
  `img_user` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `usuarios`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`login`);
```

Comment: a mensagem de erro é clara, está tentando inserir novamente o mesmo valor 'nome.sobrenome -1' para o campo que é chave primária

Comment: pois é. mas o banco está vazio.

Comment: mostre o comando `insert` que está usando. a mensagem é clara, com certeza tentou incluir mais de uma vez o mesmo registro com o mesmo valor. Veja o exemplo aqui que fiz e não dá erro o insert na tabela com essa estrutura: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c2797/1

Comment: Resolvido, o problema era outro insert que tinha posto para outra tabela e lá este usuário já estava.

Comment: não disse que a mensagem era clara? ;) boa sorte